# Passing Parameter to controller using partialView

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have one PartialView that has been Included inside two other views.

How would I be able to pass parameter from PartialView to main Controller of each View.

```
@Html.Partial("_Video","file1.xml")
```

and

```
@Html.Partial("_Video","file2.xml")
```

I want to be able to get the parameter value on Get method on each controller.

```
        //Controller1 
        // GET: //
        public ActionResult Index(){
             "file1.xml"
        }

        //Controller2
        // GET: //
        public ActionResult Index(){
             "file2.xml"
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just been solving this problem myself so hope it helps you.

In your view cshtml:

```
@Html.Action("_Video", "Controller1", new { paramValue = "some string" } )
```

You'll need to create a partial view named "_Video.cshtml" in this case (defining the correct model type via the @model directive) and in your controller:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult _Video(String paramValue) {
   // paramValue == "some string"
   // .. do something with aModel ...
   return PartialView(aModel);
}
```

However, if you're wanting to return xml or similar data content check that a view model container, Web Api or RESTful data calls aren't better fits (search on the "Json()" function if you're calling from client script too).

HTH